# Add a progress bar for commands running in parallel in shell script and track the exit_code

Tags: python, bash, shell, parallel-processing

I am using a single script to run multiple python and shell scripts.
Few are running in parallel using `&`. My requirement is to track the progress of this parallel running task and show it also i would like to get the exit_code for scripts and if any scripts fail during the execution log it saying script-1/2/3 got failed due to x reasons.

I tried using below set of code. Every thing is working for serial processing but 
for parallel processing commands i am getting last execution process Id:

```
#!/bin/bash
LOG_DIR_LOC=$1
export python_path='/usr/bin/python'
export log_file=${LOG_DIR_LOC}/log_parallel_exec_`date "+%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S"`.log
export script1='/home/test-arg.py'
export script2='/home/parallel.py'
export script3='/home/test.sh'
pids=""
echo -ne '#....................................................................................................  (1%)\r'
sleep .5


${python_path} ${script1} a b >> ${log_file} 2>&1 &
pids+=($!)
echo -ne '#################################################....................................................  (40%)\r'
sleep .5

${python_path} ${script2} c d >> ${log_file} 2>&1 &
pids+=($!)
echo -ne '###############################################################################......................  (70%)\r'
sleep .5

sh ${script3} >> ${log_file} 2>&1 &
pids+=($!)
echo -ne '##################################################################################################.... (98%)\r'
sleep .5


wait 
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "SUCCESS - Job exited with a status of $?" >> ${log_file} 2>&1
else
    echo "FAILED - Job exited with a status of $?" >> ${log_file} 2>&1
fi
done
echo -ne '#####################################################################################################  (100%)\r'
sleep .5
```

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/344360/117037

Comment: You seem to have 3 parallel processes writing to the same, single log file. This is not going to work out well.

Comment: I agree that something i can modify to write in 3 log files. the challenge how to keep track of progress when scripts are running in parallel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to print the status for all the processes at the end, do it for each

```
print_status() {
    r=$?
    if [ $r -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "SUCCESS - Job exited with a status of $r" >> ${log_file} 2>&1
    else
        echo "FAILED - Job exited with a status of $r" >> ${log_file} 2>&1
    fi
}

(${python_path} ${script1} a b >> ${log_file} 2>&1; print_status)  &
```

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% certain what you are trying to do exactly with all this sleeps and pids, but I think that **GNU Parallel** can do whatever it is pretty simply and succinctly.

In essence, I think your script amounts to this:

```
cat << EOF | parallel --dry-run --tag
python a b
python c d
bash xyz
EOF
```

So, that will do a dry-run (without actually doing anything, but telling you what it would do) and tag all output lines so they can be differentiated from each other. The three scripts (2x Python +1x bash) will be run in parallel.

You can add a progress bar with `--bar` or `--eta` after `parallel`.

You can handle failures and retries by looking in the [manpages](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html) for `--halt` and `--resume-failed` and `--retry-failed`.

You can also run the jobs across multiple computers that you have `ssh` access to, and control how many you run in parallel.

Comment: Thanks Mark...I agree about GNU just wondering is any other way to achieve same ?  any alternatives. And i am just trying to run few scripts in parallel and log their progress status.